# How to use download attribute in vue?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I can set

```html
download='filename'
```

in html a tag. Now in vue template, I go like this

```
:download="item.name"
```

in a v-for loop, but it doesn't work. The file I download is not named as 'name' value of v-for loop item.
This is my loop part.

```html
<div v-for="(item, index) in attachmentFile" :key="item.id">
  <a :href="item.url" :download="item.name">
    <div class="icon-holder icon-download"></div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: You should add id as key to your vue v-for

Comment: @mhrabiee Do you mean bind key on v-for loop? I've already done it.

Comment: please provide more code

Comment: can you show your loop in code... not just download part?

Comment: check this https://codepen.io/softkhalid/pen/rXpxKg

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim Just add my loop part

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="app">
<div v-for="(item, index) in attachmentFile" :key="item.id">
{{item}}
  <a :href="item.url" :download="item.name">
    <div class="icon-holder icon-download">AAAAA</div>
  </a>
</div>
</div>


var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    attachmentFile: [{id:"1", name: "filename", url: "url"}]
  }
});
```

InnerHTML of div tag is empty so you couldn't see any result.